# Equivalent from NSHOUR of Excel in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In an Excel report that is executed, take the time as an integer (example 61236) and apply an Excel function NSHOUR to convert it to hh:mm:ss format

Is this:

```
=NSHOUR(INT([61236]/10000), INT(RESIDUE([61236], 10000) / 100), RESIDUE(,100))
```

How would the equivalent be in SQL Server, to convert that integer to a time format?

Comment: Please tell us what research you have done, what options you have considered, and where you are stuck.

Comment: I can't find any reference to a function called `NSHOUR` in Excel... are you sure it isn't a custom function?

Comment: _In an excel report_ do you mean something like an SSRS report that generates Excel files? Could `NSHOUR` be a custom function in the report?

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL it would be:

```
TIMEFROMPARTS(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CAST(61236 AS varchar(6))),5, 2)), REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CAST(61236 AS varchar(6))), 3, 2)), RIGHT(CAST(61236 AS varchar(6)), 2), 0, 0)
```

Equivalent for NSHOUR is TIMEFROMPARTS() - however in SQL you can't use calculations as in Excel - you have to split the number different way.
Easiest is to cast whole number as string then cut it with RIGHT() and SUBSTRING() functions. REVERSE() must be used as sometimes time may be just one digit so you cant split from left and SUBSTRING() in T-SQL can't count from right. In MySQL you could just use negative start points.